# Join query in sequalizer

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following four models

**User**

```
user_id
user_email
```

**Group**

```
group_id
group_name
```

**GroupUser**

```
group_user_id
user_id
group_id
```

**Permits**

```
permit_id
user_id
```

**Assosications**

```
  User.hasOne(models.UserOption,{foreignKey: 'user_id'});  
  User.hasOne(models.GroupUser,{foreignKey: 'user_id'});
  User.hasMany(models.Permit,{foreignKey: 'user_id'});

  Group.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
  Group.hasMany(models.GroupUser, { foreignKey: 'group_id' });
  Permit.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

**Code I have tried**

```
User.findAndCountAll({
                    where: query,
                    attributes: ["user_id", "user_email"],
                    order: order,
                    distinct: true,
                    include: [{
                        model: UserOption
                    }, {
                        model: GroupUser,
                        include: [{
                            model: Group
                        }]
                    },{
                        model : Permit,
                        attributes : ["user_id","permit_id","first_name","last_name"]
                    }]
                })
                .then(function(result) {
                    res.status(200).json({ "message": "success", "data": result });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    res.status(500).json({ "error": "some database error occured!" });
                });
```

How can I user sequalize to get user list along with permits of users belongs to the group.

Means if A, B, C belongs to group1 then I want list A  along with permits of A,B,C

Comment: User.findAndCountAll({
       where: where_query,
        attributes: ["user_id", "user_email"],
        distinct: true,
         include: [{
              model: UserOption
          },{
             model : Permit,
             attributes : ["user_id","permit_id","first_name","last_name"]
            }, {
               model: GroupUser,
               include: [{
                    model: Group
                 }]
             }],
             offset: offset,
             limit: limit
   })
    .then(function(result) {
           res.json({ "data": result });
    });

Comment: update your question, add the model definitions (the part where you set the relationships) and include the formatted query.